# Is python's with statement really necessary to ensure a file is closed?

Tags: python, file, with-statement

It is typically said that you should use a with statement when working with files in python, so that regardless of whether the operations on the file succeed the file will be closed. For example:

```
with open('somefile') as f:
    # do stuff to file
```

instead of something like:

```
try:
    f = open('somefile')
    # do stuff to file
except Exception as e:
    print 'error: %s' % e
finally:
    f.close()
```

However, I've also heard that Python's GC will take care of it anyway, so it isn't necessary.

Is this true? If so, why is it a pattern commonly suggested?

Comment: gc is not what you can't expect from and taken into account. it's a good habbit anyway.

Comment: That won't work if the exception happens while opening the file, since it won't be able to close it. so you might want to put the `f = open('somefile')` before the **try** statement. otherwise, don't see why it would not work

Comment: what? ... I didnt understand a lot of that comment @HuStmpHrrr.... in CPython, especially for reading, it is really not necessary ... (that said it is a good habbit (I agree with that) to wrap it in the `with` statement)

Comment: @JoranBeasley http://overcompensating.com/oc/index.php?comic=272

Comment: there fixed :P thats why I wasnt an english major :P @jonrsharpe

Comment: There are really two things involved. The first is reference counting (delete the object at the point where its references reach zero) which does 99% of the job, and the second is garbage collection which works with objects that have weird references (like circular references) that are not detected by the first method.

Comment: @JoranBeasley FWIW I did a degree in Physics!

Comment: @JoranBeasley `unnecessary` is really not a good word to allow a programmer to bring mess, even though some environment can collect some mess.

Comment: The CPython GC will take care of it in *most* cases. However, that is not the only version of Python. PyPy's GC behaves quite differently, and may take way longer to clean it up. Other implementations may not clean it up at all. Using with makes it clearer to the interpreter *and to other developers* how long you need the file to be open.

Comment: I find the `with` clause requirement very annoying. Things like `reader = csv.reader(open('somefile.csv'))` also fall prey to its demands.

Comment: Its perfectly safe in CPython, especially when you are just reading ...  not good practice since its an implementation detail and in general it is recommended to avoid doing this ... (I still do it regularly though)

Comment: there are some situations where the GC may not get to run (interpreter segfaults, or `kill -9`ing the interpreter's process, for example)

Comment: @roippi - its reference counting, not garbage collection, at play here.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, and gc runs when refcount drops to 0, which only happens at the end of your file if you don't use a `with` statement, so...

Comment: i have never ever *ever* ever seen opening a fh in read mode breaking when using CPython regardless of with statement ... that said I do understand full well that its bad practice to rely on an implementation detail